# Suggest a project so that I can learn the Model - View - Controller

Tags: model-view-controller

i am new to the web and i understand that MVC is very important to web development. I'd like to do a project that could help me understand the MVC.
Plus, I also can't clearly understand what it is actually. i mean i can't find any good lesson or article that describes to the n00b. so if you guys could help me in that matter too that would be most appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In very short, MVC is a way to isolate behavior of the Model (e.g database), View(e.g webpage in html) and Controller(e.g code in c#) so they don't depend on each other. Why? So you can manage the html side without affecting the code or database and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with CodeIgniter. It is a great MVC framework written in PHP. While you build a site in it, you can look at the code and learn how it works.

But remember, as with each design pattern, using it should not be a goal per se. Using a design pattern can help you find and build good generic solutions, but you shouldn't feel too bad if it doesn't work out exactly as you'd like. You'll learn and do better (or differently) next time and you're always free to skip or alter the pattern. It's just a tool.